# how to use ajax to display json returned from action in asp.net mvc5

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp.net mvc5 project .I am using a webapi to get data from another server so I use below code to read data from server

```
 public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> webapicheap(string from,string to)
        {
            string url = "http://charter724.ir/webservice/list_period_date.php?from="+from+"&to="+to+"&id=367&%20key=EmlyCD8JOWX22cL8IuNBju5K5";
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // TempData["str"] = responseBody;
            return responseBody;
        }
```

so I use below script to call above action so after that an string named responseBody is returned to ajax script in the view so now I want to use this information that I dont know how to do this. please help me to do this action.

```
<script>
   function f3() {
             var from = $("#cou option:selected").val();
             var to = $("#destin option:selected").val();
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Home/webapicheap',
                 data: { from: from,to:to },
                 type: 'post',
                 dataType: 'text',
                 success: function (data) {
                  //   alert(data);
                     results = JSON.parse(data);
                     //   alert(data.data)
                     //if (country_id != "" && zone_code != "" && duration != "" && birthday != "") {
                     //    fPrice(data.token);
                     //}
                     $("#destin").html;
                     $.each(results, function (idx, res) {
                         alert(res.result.price)
                         $("#lbl1").append("<div>" + res.result.price + "</div>");
                     })
                 },
                 error: function (x, y, z) {
                     alert('fail')
                     //alert(x.responseText);
                     //alert(z);
                 }
             });

         }

</script>
```

output of the webapi

```
{"from":"\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646","from_code":"87","to":"\u0645\u0634\u0647\u062f","to_code":"109","result":[{"week":"\u0633\u0647 \u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","date_flight":"05\/12","price":"","link":"Result.html?t=YTo2OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDIiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7aToxMDAwMDtzOjI6InRvIjtpOjEwMDAxO3M6Mzoic2VjIjtpOjE0NzAxNjAxNDE7czo2OiJzZWNrZXkiO2k6MTgzMztzOjQ6InR5cGUiO3M6Mzoic3lzIjt9"},{"price":"136,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/13","type_flight":"5","week":"\u0686\u0647\u0627\u0631\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDMiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"129,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/14","type_flight":"5","week":"\u067e\u0646\u062c\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDQiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"120,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/15","type_flight":"5","week":"\u062c\u0645\u0639\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDUiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"125,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/16","type_flight":"5","week":"\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDYiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"130,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/17","type_flight":"5","week":"\u06cc\u06a9\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDciO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"141,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/18","type_flight":"5","week":"\u062f\u0648\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDgiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"159,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/19","type_flight":"5","week":"\u0633\u0647 \u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMDkiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"181,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/20","type_flight":"5","week":"\u0686\u0647\u0627\u0631\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMTAiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"183,400
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/21","type_flight":"5","week":"\u067e\u0646\u062c\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMTEiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"171,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/22","type_flight":"5","week":"\u062c\u0645\u0639\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMTIiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"171,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/23","type_flight":"5","week":"\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMTMiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"141,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/24","type_flight":"5","week":"\u06cc\u06a9\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMTQiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"148,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/25","type_flight":"5","week":"\u062f\u0648\u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMTUiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="},{"price":"161,000
\u062a\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646","from":"10000","to":"10001","date_flight":"05\/26","type_flight":"5","week":"\u0633\u0647 \u0634\u0646\u0628\u0647","link":"Result.html?t=YTo1OntzOjQ6ImRhdGUiO3M6MTA6IjIwMTYtMDgtMTYiO3M6NDoiZnJvbSI7czo1OiIxMDAwMCI7czoyOiJ0byI7czo1OiIxMDAwMSI7czozOiJzZWMiO2k6MTQ3MDE2MDE0MTtzOjY6InNlY2tleSI7aToxODMzO30="}],"ndate":1,"ldate":-1,"next_name":"15 \u0631\u0648\u0632 \u0628\u0639\u062f","prev_name":"15 \u0631\u0648\u0632 \u0642\u0628\u0644","path_name":"\u0645\u0633\u06cc\u0631 \u067e\u0631\u0648\u0627\u0632\u06cc "}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: I can not show value of "from"  and "price" and "to"  in label tag and how to write success function in ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON result contains the actual results array under the `result` property.
Try changing the line `results = JSON.parse(data);` to `results = JSON.parse(data).result;`

Also, the line `$("#destin").html;` is doing nothing - remove it.